# How to center 3D cursor on object

Tags: edit-mode

I have a complex object (see image below of multiple docks at Vancouver Harbour) and wondering is there a way to center the 3D cursor with relation to the extremities on the x and Y axis (leaving Z axis alone). Is this possible. Note that the 3D cursor appears to be dead center but it's not.
[image]

Comment: you can s<use the 3D cursor: Select the vertices you want in Edit mode, press Shift S > Cursor to Selected, then back to Object mode, right click > Origin to 3D Cursor

Comment: Thanks moonboots. Another tip for my growing text file of tips. It worked perfectly although it did also center on the Z axis which I didn't want although that was easy to remedy. Thanks again.

Comment: If it centered on the Z axis then maybe because the vertices you chose were distributed on the Z axis as well. So to explain with an easy example: if you have a cube and you want the 3D cursor to be centered on X and Y, but the Z should stay on the bottom face of the cube, then you should select only those four vertices of the bottom face. If you want the cursor centered on X and Y and the top face of the cube, select the vertices on top. Same goes for other axes.

Comment: Thanks Gordon (for both replies). Actually I want the 3D cursor to remain at around 0.150 metres from the bottom (all the docks are floating and in MSFS the position of where the 3D cursor is on the Z axis results in where the object is placed and so 0.150m results in the docks having the bottom 0.150 under water).  I think I understand from what you state that the 3D cursor on the Z axis can only be placed either at the top or bottom? Anyway it is dead easy to zoom in and 'grab Z' to an approximate 0.150 metres from the base (doesn't have to be exact).

Comment: @JohnArnold No, top and bottom were examples. The cursor can be centered around all vertices you select. In my simple example of course the cube only has top and bottom vertices in Z direction. If you want the cursor at a specific level above or below the selected vertices and there are none at the exact level you need, than choose the bottom ones and add 0.15 m to the cursor's Z location. Press N in the viewport to bring up the sidebar, go to _View_ tab, there you can enter values for the cursor. By the way, if you begin comments with my username I get notified and can answer quicker ;)

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann Thanks Gordon. At present positioning the 3D cursor 0.15 m above bottom isn't having the desired result in MSFS and my entire object (floating floatplane docks) 'float' above the water. I have to position my object so that the 3D cursor is about 0.8m above the bottom which is annoying as I'm sure it used to be ok set at 0.15. Anyway that is a problem for me in MSFS. BTW when adding your name is that done manually (like I just did) by typing @ plus your name?

Comment: @JohnArnold If you do it manually, you have to take the @ and the username without spaces inbetween. But in a thread like this if you type the first letters after @ there's usually a small pop-up window appearing above the name to suggest a user that's featured in the thread. Note that if you comment on a question or answer you cannot link the author of said question / answer, since they will be notified by default of comments. And you can only link one single user in your comment, no more.

Comment: Thanks Gordon I will try to remember all of that. Where can I go online here to read all about these things? I have had to be advised/reminded about all sorts of thing such as clicking 'this answer is useful' etc most of which I have never seen on any other forum web site. BTW what do I need to do to receive emails when answers to me questions are posted as at present I am making a shortcut (of the url to my question) on my benchtop which I click on from time to time to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is a way to do exactly what you want:

- Open the sidebar (shortcut <kbd>n</kbd>)
- go to the View tab
- hover over *3D Cursor -> Location: -> Z value field*
- copy the Z value (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd>)
- go to the 3D window and select the X and Y extremes.
- Snap the 3D Cursor to the selection (shortcut <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> and click "Cursor to Selected" or type <kbd>2</kbd>)
- hover over *3D Cursor -> Location: -> Z value field*
- paste the Z value (shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd>)

Here's the sidebar showing the appropriate Z value:[image: Sidebar showing the appropriate Z value]

This will move the 3D Cursor twice.  First to the exact center, which may mean changing the Z value; and then resetting Z to its previous value.

Comment: Thanks Marty I've learned something new (distance of cursor from the X Y and Z axis). What is the intersection of all axis called? Also how is the position of the 3D cursor relevant? The position relevant on the Z axis appears to control the height of the base of the object is in relation to ground (or water) level when the object is placed in Microsoft Flight Simulator ie if the position on the Z axis is too high or too low then the object appears either floating in mid air or buried.

Comment: The intersection of all axis, (0, 0, 0) is called the origin.  The 3D cursor is where new objects are added in object mode, or new geometry in edit mode. It can also be used as a pivot point so that the rotation command rotates around it.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have seen 'origin' elsewhere and now know more. I see that an object can be dragged below the origin (Z axis only) and hadn't considered that before - I have created an object for Microsoft Flight Simulator (a floating seaplane dock) which I want to display (in MSFS) partly submerged (to allow for the troughs between waves and not show the base of the dock) and was trying to achieve that with where the 3D cursor is. Is it possible to drag a model so that the base is a set/fixed distance below the origin point (on the Z axis only)?

Comment: Yes, you do this in object mode by selecting the object and tapping the g (for "go") key to move it.  You can make it move along only the Z axis by tapping z.  I don't know if this will move the object when you export it to FlightSim, though.

Comment: Thanks for that. Something stored in the model must 'tell' MSFS where to place the object in relation to is base and ground level. I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

You could first set the Origin to Center of Mass, then snap the 3D Cursor to Object. Then set Z to 0 again.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for another method to achieve what I wanted. I had already used moonboots method before your reply appeared and it worked apart from the fact that it also centered the 3D cursor on the Z axis which I didn't want although that was easy to fix. Will your method center on X and Y axis only or all all axis? Oh I don't have Z at 0 as the object is floating docks and the 3D cursor position places the object at water level so need to be just above the 'bottom' of the object to allow for wave height.

Comment: @JohnArnold This method also centers on all axes. To have the cursor at a certain Z location other than 0, use the method I described in the comment under your question or simply enter a different Z value for the cursor instead of 0.

Comment: FYI   I feel that I now believe that the 'origin point' is used (must be written to the output file(s)  within MSFS to orient the object in relation to ground and water level. Using information above to position 'origin point' to the base of the object and then moving everything (All Grab Z -0.15m) exporting to my MSFS application to build the scenery, my floating docks object now appears with the bottom 0.15m (approx) under the water.  I did not move the 3D cursor and don't know if it is necessary apart from within Blender to 'spin' the object around. Thanks for your help.